# Trying to group several rows based on donatedmoney status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm really struggling with this. I just can't seem to figure it out. I've got the concept in my head but don't exactly know how to put my plain language understanding of how to solve the problem into the correct Syntax.

Here is the question.

> Give me a list of all donors and their addresses categorized by whether they donated art, money, or both.

Here is the set up for the tables.

> CareTakers: CareTakerID, CareTakerName
>
> Donations: DonationID, DonorID, DonatedMoney, ArtName, ArtType, ArtAppraisedPrice, ArtLocationBuilding, ArtLocationRoom, CareTakerID
>
> Donors: DonorID, DonorName, DonorAddress

Here is what I have for my code so far.

```
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT(DonorName), DonorAddress
    FROM 
    Donors JOIN Donations ON Donors.DonorID = Donations.DonorID
    GROUP BY 
    DonatedMoney
    HAVING 
    DonatedMoney = 'Y' OR DonatedMoney = 'N' OR DonatedMoney = 'Y' AND ArtName IS NOT NULL
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Wich is the spected result? Where are you having trouble? Also put some sample data so we can help you

Comment: Have you ever used a CASE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use a `having` clause?  The question specifies no filtering.  The following summarizes the donations to get what you need and then joins the results back to the `donors` table:

```
select d.*, don.DonationType
from donors d join
     (select don.donorid,
             (case when sum(case when donatedmoney = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                        sum(case when artname is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                   then 'Both'
                   when sum(case when donatedmoney = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                   then 'Money'
                   when sum(case when artname is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                   then 'Art'
                   else 'Neither'
              end) as DonationType
      from donations don
      group by don.donorid
     ) don
     on d.donorid = don.donorid
```